# useState Callback vs useReducer in React

Tags: reactjs

In React, is applying callback with useState hook the same as using the hook, useReducer?

If no, what is the difference?

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: Anyone have an answer for this question?

Comment: Any answer for this? #React